# A paradox to law of conservation of angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, free-body-diagram, string

I came across the following problem:

> A small body of mass $M$ tied to a non stretchable string moves over a smooth horizontal plane. The other end is being drawn into a hole with constant speed. Find thread tension as a function of distance $r$ between the body and hole if ar $r=r_1$ the angular velocity $\omega=\omega_1$.

The problem is easy. The path will look like

[image]

One can easily conserve angular momentum about O which yields:
$rv=r_1v_1$ (where $v$ is the tangential velocity)

$v=r_1v_1/r$
Now $ T=ma$
Thus $ T=mr\omega^2$.
But my confusion is regarding some other thing. Let at a time instant the particle be at a distance $r$ from hole and its velocity be $v$ as follows:

[image]

Now at that instant the body will have two velocity components 1) $V$perpendicular to the rope and 2) $v_2$ radially towards the hole ($v_2$ being the constant speed with which the rope is being drawn ). But then the tension will be radially towards the hole and thus perpendicular to the component $v$. Tension being perpendicular to $v$ cannot change the magnitude of $v$ (That's what we were taught). And radial velocity should always be $v_2$. Thus by this logic component $v$ should never  change and remain equal to initial value $r_1v_1$. What is the explanation behind this disagreement?

Comment: There is no disagreement here. I think you're confusing tangential velocity with angular velocity. Those two are different things. Tangential velocity will not change. Angular velocity changes (becomes faster) when radius decreases (as you already calculated).

Comment: Think about [this tractor](https://www.deere.co.in/assets/images/region-1/products/tractors/d-series-tractors/john-deere-india-d-series-tractors.jpg) for example. The ground speed of the tractor is the same for both the small and large tyres, but the smaller tyre rotates faster because it has a smaller radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tension being perpendicular to  cannot change the magnitude of

This statement is the problem. The tension is not perpendicular to the velocity.

The tension is in the radial direction and as you yourself noted there is a radial component of the velocity. So the two vectors are not perpendicular and thus the tension can and does change the magnitude of the velocity

Edit: the above assumed that $v$ was the velocity, but the OP intended $v$ as just the tangential component of the velocity. That is also problematic for a different reason.

In normal Cartesian coordinates it is true that a force in one direction will not cause any change in the magnitude of the perpendicular component. This is the basis of projectile motion where the horizontal velocity is constant under a vertical force.

This same reasoning does not hold in polar coordinates where the basis vector in the radial direction is $\hat r(r,\theta)$ and the basis vector in the angular direction is $\hat \theta(r,\theta)$. Consider what happens when the string is cut. At that moment and thereafter the forces in both the $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ directions are zero. The ball initially has zero "radial velocity" ($v_r=dr/dt$) and pure "tangential velocity" ($v_\theta=r \ d\theta/dt$). The velocity vector is $\vec v = v_r \hat r + v_\theta \hat \theta$, which remains constant, so $v_r$ and $v_\theta$ change to compensate as $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ change from point to point in the polar coordinates. Specifically, $v_r$ begins increasing and $v_\theta$ begins decreasing. As time goes on, $v_\theta$ gets smaller and smaller approaching zero, and $v_r$ gets larger and larger approaching the initial tangential velocity. All with no force applied.

Comment: By $v$ I specifically mean the component perpendicular to the string. Then will tension also change the magnitude of $v$ only?

Comment: @Dale What do you mean by "tangential velocity"? Tangent to what? it cannot be to the trajectory because by definition the trajectory is tngent to the velocity vector at any point. I see that in many places the term is used as equivalent to "linear velocity" as opposite to angular velocity. But here you use radial velocity so I suppose you mean the component along the unit vector associated with the angular polar coordinate.

Comment: @nasu oops, you are completely correct. I by "tangential velocity" I meant $r \ d\theta/dt$ and for "radial velocity" I meant $dr/dt$. I will clarify that in the answer